# Bind List containing different elements to Itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application using MVVM software architecture. In my ViewModel I have a property called SelectedAttributes.

```
private ObservableCollection<NodeAttributeViewModel> _selectedAttributes;
public ObservableCollection<NodeAttributeViewModel> SelectedAttributes
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedAttributes;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedAttributes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAttributes");
    }
}
```

NodeAttributeViewModel is defined as

```
class NodeAttributeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public enum ElementType { BOOL, STRING }
    public ElementType Type { get; set; }
    public NodeAttribute Attribute { get; set; }

    public string AttributeName
    {
        get
        {
            return Attribute.Attribute;
        }
        set
        {
            Attribute.Attribute = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AttributeName");
        }
    }

    public string AttributeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Attribute.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!Attribute.Value.Equals(value))
            {
                Attribute.Value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AttributeValue");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to bind the SelectedAttributes list to a ItemsControl. Depending on the Type of element of list element, I want to display a checkbox(for boolean), TextBox ( for String). Currently I am able display all the elements in a TextBox. I dont know how to display checkbox for elements whose type is Boolean

Here is my Xaml

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="2"  Margin="9,6,9,6">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedAttributes}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Margin="4">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttributeName}" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AttributeValue}" Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>                    
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You will have to create a template for each type and then either use datatrigger on Type property to set the template or you can use a templateselector to select which template to display

Comment: You may use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to select between different DataTemplates depending on the value of the `ElementType` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

you can make use of `DataTrigger` to control what type of editor should be displayed for different type of attribute

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Margin="4">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttributeName}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="text"
                            Text="{Binding AttributeValue}"
                            Grid.Column="1" />
                <CheckBox x:Name="check"
                            IsChecked="{Binding AttributeValue}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Grid>
            <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"
                        Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}"
                            Value="BOOL">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="check"
                        Value="Visible" />
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="text"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I have added a `CheckBox` in the `same column` as `TextBox` and set it's Visibility to Collapsed by default

when the value of `Type` is `BOOL` the trigger setters will `swap` the `Visibility` of `CheckBox` and `TextBox` hence making CheckBox appear and TextBox disappear and will also reset it back when value is not  BOOL

Answer (score 0):

You can put Trigger on your Checkbox visiblity depending on your Type property

```
             <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Margin="4">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox>
                                <CheckBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="BOOL">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </CheckBox.Style>
                            </CheckBox>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding AttributeName}" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding AttributeValue}" Grid.Column="2" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
```